# Inference about Slope coefficient in R

Tags: r, stat, lm

By default `lm` summary test slope coefficient equal to zero. My question is very basic. I want to know how to test slope coefficient equal to non-zero value. One approach could be to use `confint` but this does not provide p-value. I also wonder how to do one-sided test with `lm`.

```
ctl <- c(4.17,5.58,5.18,6.11,4.50,4.61,5.17,4.53,5.33,5.14)
trt <- c(4.81,4.17,4.41,3.59,5.87,3.83,6.03,4.89,4.32,4.69)
group <- gl(2,10,20, labels=c("Ctl","Trt"))
weight <- c(ctl, trt)
lm.D9 <- lm(weight ~ group)
summary(lm.D9)

Call:
lm(formula = weight ~ group)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.0710 -0.4938  0.0685  0.2462  1.3690 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   5.0320     0.2202  22.850 9.55e-15 ***
groupTrt     -0.3710     0.3114  -1.191    0.249    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Residual standard error: 0.6964 on 18 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.07308,    Adjusted R-squared: 0.02158 
F-statistic: 1.419 on 1 and 18 DF,  p-value: 0.249 


confint(lm.D9)
              2.5 %    97.5 %
(Intercept)  4.56934 5.4946602
groupTrt    -1.02530 0.2833003
```

Thanks for your time and effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `linearHypothesis` function from `car` package. For instance, you can check if the coefficient of `groupTrt` equals -1 using.

```
linearHypothesis(lm.D9, "groupTrt = -1")

Linear hypothesis test

Hypothesis:
groupTrt = - 1

Model 1: restricted model
Model 2: weight ~ group

  Res.Df     RSS Df Sum of Sq      F  Pr(>F)  
1     19 10.7075                              
2     18  8.7292  1    1.9782 4.0791 0.05856 .
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your nice answer. I wonder how to do one-sided test. I tried this with `groupTrt >= -1` but it did not work.

Comment: How about halving the *p* value ... ??  (That would be the standard answer for "how do I get a one-sided *p* value", although you should check the comments below @kohske's answer)

Answer (score 8):

as @power says, you can do by your hand.
here is an example:

```
> est <- summary.lm(lm.D9)$coef[2, 1]
> se <- summary.lm(lm.D9)$coef[2, 2]
> df <- summary.lm(lm.D9)$df[2]
> 
> m <- 0
> 2 * abs(pt((est-m)/se, df))
[1] 0.2490232
> 
> m <- 0.2
> 2 * abs(pt((est-m)/se, df))
[1] 0.08332659
```

and you can do one-side test by omitting `2*`.

**UPDATES**

here is an example of two-side and one-side probability:

```
> m <- 0.2
> 
> # two-side probability
> 2 * abs(pt((est-m)/se, df))
[1] 0.08332659
> 
> # one-side, upper (i.e., greater than 0.2)
> pt((est-m)/se, df, lower.tail = FALSE)
[1] 0.9583367
> 
> # one-side, lower (i.e., less than 0.2)
> pt((est-m)/se, df, lower.tail = TRUE)
[1] 0.0416633
```

note that sum of upper and lower probabilities is exactly 1.

Comment: I don't think "omitting the 2" is statistically correct. I think you need to substitute 1.644854 = qnorm(.95), and then only look in direction specified by the ast yet unstated hypothesis.

Comment: That looks better. Maybe I didn't understand what you were doing before. I am more comfortable looking at mean + 1.64*se  (or mean - 1.64*se depending on the specific hypothesis) versus 0. It seems to me that most people who ask this question have a marginal result that they are just trying to push across the artificial "finish line" of 0.05.

Comment: Or use `t.test` on the data directly; see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The [smatr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/smatr/index.html) package has a `slope.test()` function with which you can use OLS.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to all the other good answers, you could use an offset.  It's a little trickier with categorical predictors, because you need to know the coding.

```
lm(weight~group+offset(1*(group=="Trt")))
```

The `1*` here is unnecessary but is put in to emphasize that you are testing against the hypothesis that the difference is 1 (if you want to test against a hypothesis of a difference of `d`, then use `d*(group=="Trt")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `t.test` to do this for your data. The `mu` parameter sets the hypothesis for the difference of group means. The `alternative` parameter lets you choose between one and two-sided tests.

```
t.test(weight~group,var.equal=TRUE)

        Two Sample t-test

data:  weight by group 
t = 1.1913, df = 18, p-value = 0.249
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0 
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.2833003  1.0253003 
sample estimates:
mean in group Ctl mean in group Trt 
            5.032             4.661 



t.test(weight~group,var.equal=TRUE,mu=-1)

        Two Sample t-test

data:  weight by group 
t = 4.4022, df = 18, p-value = 0.0003438
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to -1 
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.2833003  1.0253003 
sample estimates:
mean in group Ctl mean in group Trt 
            5.032             4.661
```

Comment: Good alternative. Note that t test is available only with one categorical variable having two levels.

Answer (score -1):

Code up your own test. You know the estimated coeffiecient and you know the standard error. You could construct your own test stat.

Comment: while your comment makes complete sense, you should remember that this is R. so chances that a trivial test is already implemented is extremely high, and worth checking before spending time coding it up. of course, it has its own instructional value.

Comment: This isn't necessarily a bad answer, if you added some example code to illustrate how one might do this.

Comment: This can be trivial to code up. Check a first year econometrics textbook.